# Infinite loop while adding a row in bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events, bootstrap-table

I have a table which has 5 rows and i want to add another row dynamically and i dont want to add that row through onclick event. I want that row to be added automatically so i chose 'post-header.bs.table' event. But now i am running into infinite loop and the browser crashes because of that. I dont know why it is running into infinite loop and please let me know how to solve this.

Code:

```
 $(function () {
                    $('#Table2').on('post-header.bs.table', function () { 
                        $('#Table2').bootstrapTable('insertRow', {
                            index:5,
                            row: {
                                Data:{
                                practice: 'score',
                                input: '12345'
                                }
                            }                  
                        });
                    });
                });
```

I need to pass the data in the row:{Data:{practice:'score',input:'12345'}} format.

Comment: The `post-header.bs.table` event fires after the table is rendered, which also happens (re-rendering) when you add new rows to the table. So adding rows, fires the `post-header.bs.table`, which adds new rows, and so on.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan - ya i found it.. so can i use .one instead of .on to run the event only once..???

Comment: Yes, that would be a good solution! You could also register it to a click on a button, but in that way it wouldn't be dynamic, which you stated you wanted.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan : ok thanks.. i used .one and it is working now.. :)